# Vector, and direction derivative problem

Tags: derivatives, vectors

Find the unit vector in the direction in which f(x, y, z) = 4e^(xy) * cos(z) decreases most rapidly at (0, 1, pi/4) and find the rate of decrease of f in that direction

I need detail explanation for approaching this question. thanks.

Comment: What have you tried already? What do you already know about the problem? Which methods do you think you need to use but maybe don't see how to apply them? Where are you stuck? You need to show effort, otherwise people tend to downvote your question.

Comment: I have answer sheet, but it doesn't really help me to approach by understandable way

Comment: If you have really no idea how to start you could always ask for a hint.

Comment: Yeh. I didn't ask for answer, but explanation for approaching this question. So, it can also be a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f$ decreases most rapidly in the direction of $-\nabla f$. Thus, you want to consider \begin{equation}
-\nabla f = <-4ye^{xy}cosz , -4xe^{xy}cosz, 4e^{xy}sinz>
\end{equation}
Now, plug in $x=0$, $y=1$, and $z=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to get
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{v}=<\frac{-4}{\sqrt{2}}, 0, \frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}>
\end{equation}
You will need to normalize this vector to get a unit vector.